# How to REALLY enter setup on ASUS K75DE?

Tags: keyboard

I really have no idea what's going on here. I have an ASUS K75DE and both official manual and the official site says the Setup key is F2, however no matter how fast I smash the key constantly, nothing happens. I even did that process with "Fn" key pressed and again, nothing.

What's going on here?

Comment: If that's a UEFI system, you'll likely need to make sure you're actually cold booting, not rebooting or something similar . . .

Comment: Try Esc as well

Comment: thanks for you answers. ernie what you mean? I'm shutting off the laptop and then turning it on... and nothing.

Comment: @Alain - most of the newer systems with UEFI, even when you press power, are not a complete power off, but some sleep/hibernate state.  Same thing when you reboot from within in Windows; it's not the same as a hard reboot, and often you don't have time to interrupt the boot process.  To ensure a hard power off, you'll likely want to hold the power button down for several seconds.  If the battery is removable, you could try that as well to ensure a complete power cycle.

Answer (score 0):

This article suggests you should try the `DEL` key instead

- [ASUSTeK Computer Inc. -Support- Troubleshooting K75DE](http://support.asus.com/Troubleshooting/detail.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=K75DE&p=3&s=401&os=&hashedid=I8AwyjQb7UeSB0IC&no=822)

## Update

Then, this forum is worth a read

- [Need help...Asus N56vz-RH71 can't enter BIOS!](http://forum.notebookreview.com/asus/709605-need-help-asus-n56vz-rh71-cant-enter-bios.html#post9096250)

Comment: yup, I saw that before posting the question, tried it, and nothing... that's when I pass to the F2 key and still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same K75D series and had the exact issue for about 2 weeks. The machine is fast, and if you rapidly press <kbd>F2</kbd> right after it powers on, you won't miss it anymore. The default fast boot option actually makes it harder to achieve it the first time.